# RuntimeError - Unable to find subscription with identifier: when ios app try to send a message

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, websocket, actioncable

I am using WebSocket for comments on a post. ios user subscribe to the `comment_channel` and I got confirmation that the user successfully subscribed to comment_channel.

```
[ActionCable] [23] CommentRoomsChannel is transmitting the subscription confirmation
[ActionCable] [23] CommentRoomsChannel is streaming from comments_291
```

But the issue is when the user tries to comment I get this error.

```
Could not execute command from ({"identifier"=>"{\"channel\":\"CommentRoomsChannel\",\"post_id\":\"291\"}", "command"=>"message", "data"=>"{\"description\":\"Aaaa\",\"post_id\":\"291\"}"}) [RuntimeError - Unable to find subscription with identifier: {"channel":"CommentRoomsChannel","post_id":"291"}]: /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actioncable-6.0.3.2/lib/action_cable/connection/subscriptions.rb:74:in `find' | /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actioncable-6.0.3.2/lib/action_cable/connection/subscriptions.rb:55:in `perform_action' | /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actioncable-6.0.3.2/lib/action_cable/connection/subscriptions.rb:19:in `execute_command' | /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actioncable-6.0.3.2/lib/action_cable/connection/base.rb:87:in `dispatch_websocket_message' | /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.7.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/actioncable-6.0.3.2/lib/action_cable/server/worker.rb:59:in `block in invoke'
```

I have added delay but this error even occurs when users try to comment for the first time.

here's my code:

```
class CommentRoomsChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel

  def subscribed

    stream_from "comments_#{params[:post_id]}"
  end



def unsubscribed
    stop_all_streams
  end



def receive(data)
    post = Post.find_by(id: data["post_id"])
    post_data = {
      id: comment['id'],
      post_id: comment['post_id'],
      user_id: comment['user_id'],
      description: comment['description'].to_s,
      user: {
        id: current_user['id'],
        first_name: current_user['first_name'],
        last_name: current_user['last_name'],
        username: current_user['username'],
        is_hide_name: current_user['is_hide_name'],
        profile_image: current_user['profile_image']
      }
    }
    comment = current_user.comments.create!(description: data["description"], post_id: data["post_id"])
    ActionCable.server.broadcast "comments_#{data['post_id']}", post_data.as_json
    NotificationService.new(post.user_id, current_user.id, 2, data['post_id'].to_i).call unless post.user_id == current_user.id
  end
  
end
```

this error only occurs when the ios user tries to comment, the same code is working with android.

Comment: Were you able to solve it? I am facing the same too. Not able to reproduce it correctly.

Comment: @SandipMane yes, i solved the issue. by removing the post_id from the identifier.

Answer (score 0):

I resoved the issue by removing the parameter from the identifier. so before the issue my command was
`{"identifier"=>"{\"channel\":\"CommentRoomsChannel\",\"post_id\":\"291\"}"`
after removing parameter
`{"identifier"=>"{\"channel\":\"CommentRoomsChannel\"}"`